# I once was going an appendectomy

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does the phrase "I once was going an appendectomy" mean "I once was going to receive an operation - appendectomy"? But what follows appears to point out the speaker himself is a doctor who does appendectomy for his patients. Does the phrase mean that the doctor himself became a patient to receive the operation?

> **I once was going an appendectomy**. I cut into my patient’s abdomen and immediately get a weird feeling. When I looked inside, my heart dropped.

> Source: Factinate tweeted

Comment: It is a mistype. Should be "doing" not "going".

Comment: Please don't take tweets as any indication of proper English. When in doubt, throw that tweet out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there might be a typo in the sentence. If the context is a doctor speaking, then the sentence would say:

"I once was **d**oing an appendectomy. I cut into my patient’s abdomen and immediately get a weird feeling. When I looked inside, my heart dropped."

If you were a spectator heading to watch the surgery, you might say, "I once was going to see an appendectomy performed. I sat in the balcony and watched the doctor perform the operation."

Comment: It would be incorrect for a spectator to use that sentence. You "go **to**" an event; you cannot "go" an event. Furthermore, in this context, "went to" is correct and "was going to" is not.

Comment: Thanks @rjpond - I edited for clarity with your suggestions

Comment: Thanks @AlphaDraconis - I made an edit based on your suggestions